# Rails Nested Form - Unpermitted Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an Orders model that has many Items and Customers. For some reason, and I have looked high and low for a solution, I am unable to save the attributes for Items and Customers in their respected tables when using a nested form.

I'm relatively new to Rails, so my apologies if I've missed something obvious.

> Started POST "/orders" for ::1 at 2017-05-16 16:12:17 -0600 Processing
>   by OrdersController#create as HTML Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"k1QPQ560j44Mx0SNeCMBQAUGLQfEi4g0QpDfHuYeP4Zd7nVgcHJf3qXNsVQv29dV+5G0oJ7wiaoQ3Idw+DP+iw==",
>   "order"=>{"customer"=>{"name"=>"Test", "email"=>"Test",
>   "phone"=>"Test"}, "item"=>{"name"=>"Test", "ref_num"=>"Test",
>   "retail"=>"122"}, "status"=>"Test", "arrival"=>"06/06/19",
>   "tracking"=>"Test439"}, "commit"=>"Save Order"} Unpermitted
>   parameters: customer, item

Orders Controller

```
    def create
        @order = Order.new(order_params)
        @order.items.build
        @order.customers.build
        @order.save
        redirect_to @order 
    end
private
    def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:status, :arrival, :tracking, 
        customers_attributes: [:name, :phone, :email], 
        items_attributes: [:name, :ref_num, :retail])
    end
```

Orders Model

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :items
    has_many :customers
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :items, :customers
end
```

Orders Form (New)

```
<%= form_for :order, url: orders_path do |f| %>

<%# customer parameters%>
<%= f.fields_for :customers do |cu| %>
   <p>
    <%= cu.label :customer_name %><br>
    <%= cu.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= cu.label :email %><br>
    <%= cu.text_field :email %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= cu.label :phone %><br>
    <%= cu.text_field :phone %>
  </p>
<% end %>

 <%# Item parameters %>

 <%= f.fields_for :items do |it| %>

  <p>
    <%= it.label :item_name %><br>
    <%= it.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= it.label :reference_number %><br>
    <%= it.text_field :ref_num %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= it.label :retail %><br>
    <%= it.text_field :retail%>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%# order parameters%>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :status %>
  </p>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :est_arrival %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :arrival %>
  </p>

 <p>
    <%= f.label :tracking %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :tracking %>
</p>


  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>

 <% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', orders_path %>
```

Comment: Is this really coming from this form? I don't see anything wrong with the form at first glance at least.

Comment: Try using `form_for @order` on your form instead, and instantiating `@order = Order.new` on your `new` action

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `form_for :order` doesn't make reference to your model object, it makes a simple `:order` param, which doesn't takes into consideration your model's `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, thus not building `f.fields_for :customers` with `_attributes` suffix. You should instantiate a `Order` object for the expected behavior to happen in your `form_for @object` instead of just referencing a `:object` which renders only the name of the param.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I've changed `form_for :object` to `form_for @object`. Unfortunately, only fields related to orders are now showing up when the form is rendered. Do I need to make changes to :customers and :items also?

Comment: You have to also add in your controller `@object.customers.build` for the `new` action probably